# Flatten nested lists with variable length in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have nested lists in a pandas column and i want to flatten them.

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'text':[[['some','string'],['yes']],[['hello','how','are','u'],['fine','thanks']]],
               'names':[[['chris'],['peter','kate']],[['steve','john'],['kyle','eric']]]})
```

The problem here seems to be that the lists all vary in length, otherwise it could be easily solved with `.apply(np.ravel)`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for processes element wise values with list comprehension and flattening:

```
cols = ['text','names']
df5[cols] = df5[cols].applymap(lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y])
print (df5)
                                 text                      names
0                 [some, string, yes]       [chris, peter, kate]
1  [hello, how, are, u, fine, thanks]  [steve, john, kyle, eric]
```

Or:

```
cols = ['text','names']
df5[cols] = df5[cols].applymap(np.concatenate)
print (df5)
                                 text                      names
0                 [some, string, yes]       [chris, peter, kate]
1  [hello, how, are, u, fine, thanks]  [steve, john, kyle, eric]
```

Comment: i just figured for a single column you could use `apply()` instead of `applymap()` and this gives the same results

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need `itertools.chain` and `applymap`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'text':[[['some','string'],['yes']],[['hello','how','are','u'],['fine','thanks']]],
               'names':[[['chris'],['peter','kate']],[['steve','john'],['kyle','eric']]]})

print(df5.applymap(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x))))
```

**Output:**

```
                       names                                text
0       [chris, peter, kate]                 [some, string, yes]
1  [steve, john, kyle, eric]  [hello, how, are, u, fine, thanks]
```