# flatten nested list in pandas containing nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-lists, flatten

I have a table like this:

```
index | country
---------------
1     | [nan]
2     | [nan, DE]
3     | [nan, [IT, DE]]
4     | [[FR]]
5     | [[AE], nan, [AE,  MT], [MX]]
```

And i need to turn this column into a flat list of unique values without nans

```
index | country
---------------
1     | []
2     | [DE]
3     | [IT, DE]
4     | [FR]
5     | [AE, MT, MX]
```

As a first step i tried to flatten the list with this function

`df.applymap(lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y])`

But I get the following error:

`TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

I tried several other functions that I found in this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141494/flatten-nested-lists-with-variable-length-in-pandas-column) but all end up giving me the same error.

Comment: can you provide a dataframe constructor or dictionary as input?

Comment: `df.applymap(lambda x: list(set([z for y in x if isinstace(y, list) for z in y])))`. In short, `nan` values are `np.nan` and they are defined as "float" types, so this is why you get this error, when you hit a `nan` and since it's not an iterable type, it raises an exception.

Comment: ooh i see. Let me try, thanks.

Comment: it worked - if you post it as answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for any nested lists

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, Iterable) and not isinstance(el, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el
```

So recreating your df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[[[float('nan')],[float('nan'), 'DE']]],
                   [[[float('nan'), ['IT', 'DE']]]],
                   [[[['FR']]]],
                   [[[['AE'], float('nan'), ['AE',  'MT'], ['MX']]]]],columns=['country'])

df['country'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x:list(set(flatten(x)))).apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if str(i) != 'nan'])
```

gives the following output

```
    country
0   [DE]
1   [IT, DE]
2   [FR]
3   [AE, MT, MX]
```

Comment: thanks! What does "if i == i" do in the lambda?

Comment: Sorry, I just copy pasted :p fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks - I need unique sets tho you see in index 3 there is twice AE

Comment: Made a edit, should work now